# 英語が残っている、翻訳に違和感：サイトから移行された投稿

Tags: バグ, 翻訳, 英語

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/5905/revisions

> サイトから移行された投稿 to meta.ja.stackoverflow.com by ento♦

翻訳するとしたらこんな感じでしょうか。

> ento♦がmeta.ja.stackoverflow.comに移行した投稿

Comment: 開発者と相談して、適切なストリングを検討しています（`to ... by`のストリングは[かなり多い](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289671?translated=no&q=to%20by)です）